# Run a C#.NET executable with command line arguments using subprocess in python

Tags: python, c#, subprocess

Net .exe console app with command line arguments, that I need to run from a python script.

I have tried:

```
process = subprocess.check_output(r'C:\path to folder\program to execute.exe arg_1 arg_2', shell=False)

out, err = process.communicate()
errcode = process.returncode
print(errcode)

process.kill() 
process.terminate()
```

However nothing appears to happen. The code running on jupyter just a hangs indefinitely What is the correct way to perform this action? Note I have looked at 'Popen' and 'call' too but not sure which is appropriate in this case.

Comment: have you tried `subprocess.check_output(r'"C:\path to folder\program to execute.exe" arg_1 arg_2', shell=False)`?

Comment: I have now but getting the same result!

Comment: Actually this has solved the issue. Thanks